# How to implement the output of decision tree built using the ctree (party package)?

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I have built a decision tree using the `ctree` function via `party` package. it has 1700 nodes.
Firstly, is there a way in `ctree` to give the `maxdepth` argument? I tried `control_ctree` option but, it threw some error message saying couldnt find ctree function.

Also, how can I consume the output of this tree?. How can it be implemented for other platforms like SAS or SQL. I also have another doubt as to what does the value `"*  weights = 4349 "` at the end of the node signify. How will I know, that which terminal node votes for which predicted value.

Comment: Please simplify your question first,by giving an example what fucntion  you actually wrote it in your R console.

Comment: library(party)
train.treeM1<-ctree(U_ACTIVITY_FLAG_STATUS_3~
U_ARPU_M1 +
U_RCHRG_CNT_M1 +
U_LOCAL_TOT_MOU_M1 +
U_OG_CALL_CNT_M1 +
U_OG_AVG_CALL_DURATION_M1 +
U_IC_CALL_CNT_M1 +
U_IC_AVG_CALL_DURATION_M1 +
U_DED_RECHARGE_RATIO +
U_Advanced_Handset_Ratio +
U_Retailer_Baby_Care_Ratio +
U_Retailer_Born_Dead_Ratio,
data=traindata)

table(traindata$U_ACTIVITY_FLAG_STATUS_3,predict(train.treeM1))
#plot(train.treeM1,type="simple")
#plot(train.treeM1)
#summary(train.treeM1)

Comment: This is the code i have used and it has created a tree. Now i want the oputput of this tree to be implemented in SAS/SQL which is in the below mentioned format.

Comment: 1) U_OG_CALL_CNT_M1M2 <= 13; criterion = 1, statistic = 53104.0
2) U_DED_RECHARGE_RATIO <= 0; criterion = 1, statistic = 11833.82
3) U_OG_CALL_CNT_M1M2 <= 5; criterion = 1, statistic = 10453.2
4) U_IC_CALL_CNT_M1M2 <= 3; criterion = 1, statistic = 7124.4
5) U_IC_CALL_CNT_M1M2 <= 1; criterion = 1, statistic = 3304.2
6) U_Retailer_Born_Dead_Ratio <= 0.14; criterion = 1, statistic = 2241.2
7) U_OG_CALL_CNT_M1M2 <= 0; criterion = 1, statistic = 665.931
8) U_RCHRG_CNT_M1M2 <= 0; criterion = 1, statistic = 1621.802
9) U_IC_CALL_CNT_M1M2 <= 0; criterion = 1, statistic = 1680.226
10)*weights = 4349

Comment: the output goes on for some 1700 lines.... Can anyone tell me how can I decipher as to how the ending node is voting for which of possible output.

Comment: Adding a bit of example data so people can toy with this code might increase your chances of obtaining an answer. So create dummy data arbitrarily. dput can be very useful to turn your data into a textual representation which can be restored easily, making your whole code snipped a SSCCE. Please Edit in your question.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `maxdepth` option in ctree. It is located in `ctree_control()`

You can use it as follows

```
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq, controls = ctree_control(maxdepth = 3))
```

You can also restrict the split sizes and the bucket sizes to be "no less than"

```
airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq, controls = ctree_control(minsplit= 50, minbucket = 20))
```

You can also to reduce increase sensetivity and lower the P-value

```
airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq, controls = ctree_control(mincriterion = 0.99))
```

The `weights = 4349` you've mentioned is just the number of observations in that specific node. `ctree` has a default of giving a weight of 1 to every observation, but if you feel that you have observations that deserve bigger weights you can add a weights vector to the `ctree()` which have to be the same length as the data set and have to be non-negative integers. After you do that, the `weights = 4349` will have to be interpreted with caution.

One way of using `weights` is to see which observations fell in a certain node. Using the data in the example above we can perform the following

```
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq, controls = ctree_control(maxdepth = 3))
unique(where(airct)) #in order the get the terminal nodes
[1] 5 3 6 9 8
```

so we can check what fell in node number 5 for example

```
n <- nodes(airct , 5)[[1]]
x <- airq[which(as.logical(n$weights)), ]  
x
    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1      41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2      36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3      12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4      18     313 11.5   62     5   4
...
```

Using this method you can create data sets that will contain the informationn of you terminal nodes and then import them into SAS or SQL

You can also get the list of splitting conditions using the function from my answer below
[ctree() - How to get the list of splitting conditions for each terminal node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443203/ctree-how-to-get-the-list-of-splitting-conditions-for-each-terminal-node/22300768#22300768)