# ctree() - How to get the list of splitting conditions for each terminal node?

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I have an output from `ctree()` (`party` package) that looks like the following. How do I get the list of splitting conditions for each terminal node, like like `sns <= 0, dta <= 1; sns <= 0, dta > 1` and so on?

```
1) sns <= 0; criterion = 1, statistic = 14655.021
  2) dta <= 1; criterion = 1, statistic = 3286.389
   3)*  weights = 153682 
  2) dta > 1
   4)*  weights = 289415 
1) sns > 0
  5) dta <= 2; criterion = 1, statistic = 1882.439
   6)*  weights = 245457 
  5) dta > 2
   7) dta <= 6; criterion = 1, statistic = 1170.813
     8)*  weights = 328582 
   7) dta > 6
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

This function should do the job

```
 CtreePathFunc <- function (ct, data) {

  ResulTable <- data.frame(Node = character(), Path = character())

  for(Node in unique(where(ct))){
  # Taking all possible non-Terminal nodes that are smaller than the selected terminal node
  NonTerminalNodes <- setdiff(1:(Node - 1), unique(where(ct))[unique(where(ct)) < Node])


  # Getting the weigths for that node
  NodeWeights <- nodes(ct, Node)[[1]]$weights


  # Finding the path
  Path <- NULL
  for (i in NonTerminalNodes){
    if(any(NodeWeights & nodes(ct, i)[[1]][2][[1]] == 1)) Path <- append(Path, i)
  }

  # Finding the splitting creteria for that path
  Path2 <- SB <- NULL

  for(i in 1:length(Path)){
    if(i == length(Path)) {
      n <- nodes(ct, Node)[[1]]
    } else {n <- nodes(ct, Path[i + 1])[[1]]}

    if(all(data[which(as.logical(n$weights)), as.character(unlist(nodes(ct,Path[i])[[1]][[5]])[length(unlist(nodes(ct,Path[i])[[1]][[5]]))])] <= as.numeric(unlist(nodes(ct,Path[i])[[1]][[5]])[3]))){
      SB <- "<="
    } else {SB <- ">"}
    Path2 <- paste(c(Path2, paste(as.character(unlist(nodes(ct,Path[i])[[1]][[5]])[length(unlist(nodes(ct,Path[i])[[1]][[5]]))]),
                                 SB,
                                 as.character(unlist(nodes(ct,Path[i])[[1]][[5]])[3]))),
                   collapse = ", ")
  }

  # Output
  ResulTable <- rbind(ResulTable, cbind(Node = Node, Path = Path2))
  }
  return(ResulTable)
}
```

Testing

```
library(party)
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
ct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq,  controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
Result <- CtreePathFunc(ct, airq)
Result 

##   Node                               Path
## 1    5 Temp <= 82, Wind > 6.9, Temp <= 77
## 2    3            Temp <= 82, Wind <= 6.9
## 3    6  Temp <= 82, Wind > 6.9, Temp > 77
## 4    9             Temp > 82, Wind > 10.3
## 5    8            Temp > 82, Wind <= 10.3
```

Comment: Takes long time, but gives a very good response. And you forgot to put the "airq" matrix as variable.

Comment: Thanks, @Galled. Edited. I also forgot to `library(party)`. It was one of my first answers in SO, so was a bit noob there

Comment: Is there any updated version of this function that also deals with categorical explanatory variables? @DavidArenburg

Comment: @JoãoDaniel, I didn't write one. Maybe post a new question and see if someone can elaborate, as I'm not sure I'll have time to write one in the new future

Comment: @JoãoDaniel I make one.

Answer (score 8):

If you use the new recommended `partykit` implementation of `ctree()` rather than the old `party` package, then you can use the function `.list.rules.party()`. This is not yet officially exported, yet, but can be leveraged to extract the desired information.

```
library("partykit")
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
ct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq)
partykit:::.list.rules.party(ct)
##                                      3                                      5 
##             "Temp <= 82 & Wind <= 6.9" "Temp <= 82 & Wind > 6.9 & Temp <= 77" 
##                                      6                                      8 
##  "Temp <= 82 & Wind > 6.9 & Temp > 77"             "Temp > 82 & Wind <= 10.3" 
##                                      9 
##              "Temp > 82 & Wind > 10.3"
```

Comment: Is `.list.rules.party()` exported somehow now?

Comment: No, still not yet, unfortunately. If you need it in another package I would recommend the source code for now. It's not that long.

Comment: Thanks. Invoking it with `partykit:::.list.rules.party` is fine for me. I was only curious if it can be done in some neater way.

Answer (score 5):

Due I needed this function but for categorical data, I make, more or less answering the question @JoãoDaniel (I've only tested with categorical predictor variables), the next functions:

```
# returns string w/o leading or trailing whitespace
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261079/how-to-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-r
trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
getVariable <- function (x) sub("(.*?)[[:space:]].*", "\\1", x)
getSimbolo <- function (x) sub("(.*?)[[:space:]](.*?)[[:space:]].*", "\\2", x)

getReglaFinal = function(elemento) {        
    x = as.data.frame(strsplit(as.character(elemento),";"))
    Regla = apply(x,1, trim)
    Regla = data.frame(Regla)
    indice = as.numeric(rownames(Regla))
    variable = apply(Regla,1, getVariable)
    simbolo = apply(Regla,1, getSimbolo)

    ReglaRaw = data.frame(Regla,indice,variable,simbolo)
    cols <- c( 'variable' , 'simbolo' )
    ReglaRaw$tipo_corte <- apply(  ReglaRaw[ , cols ] ,1 , paste , collapse = "" )
    #print(ReglaRaw)
    cortes = unique(ReglaRaw$tipo_corte)
    #print(cortes)
    ReglaFinal = ""
    for(i in 1:length(cortes)){
        #print("------------------------------------")
        #print(cortes[i])
        #print("ReglaRaw econtrada")
        #print(ReglaRaw$indice[ReglaRaw$tipo_corte==cortes[i]])
        maximo = max(ReglaRaw$indice[ReglaRaw$tipo_corte==cortes[i]])
        #print(maximo)
        tmp = as.character(ReglaRaw$Regla[ReglaRaw$indice==maximo])
        if(ReglaFinal==""){
            ReglaFinal = tmp
        }else{
            ReglaFinal = paste(ReglaFinal,tmp,sep="; ",collapse="; ")
        }
    }
    return(ReglaFinal)
}#getReglaFinal

CtreePathFuncAllCat <- function (ct) {

  ResulTable <- data.frame(Node = character(), Path = character())

  for(Node in unique(where(ct))){

    # Taking all possible non-Terminal nodes that are smaller than the selected terminal node
    NonTerminalNodes <- setdiff(1:(Node - 1), unique(where(ct))[unique(where(ct)) < Node])

    # Getting the weigths for that node
    NodeWeights <- nodes(ct, Node)[[1]]$weights

    # Finding the path
    Path <- NULL
    for (i in NonTerminalNodes){
        if(any(NodeWeights & nodes(ct, i)[[1]][2][[1]] == 1)) Path <- append(Path, i)
    }

    # Finding the splitting creteria for that path
    Path2 <- SB <- NULL

    variablesNombres <- array()
    variablesPuntos <- list()

    for(i in 1:length(Path)){
        n <- nodes(ct, Path[i])[[1]]

        if(i == length(Path)) {
            nextNodeID = Node
        } else {
            nextNodeID = Path[i+1]
        }       

        vec_puntos  = as.vector(n[[5]]$splitpoint)
        vec_nombre  = n[[5]]$variableName
        vec_niveles = attr(n[[5]]$splitpoint,"levels")

        index = 0

        if((length(vec_puntos)!=length(vec_niveles)) && (length(vec_niveles)!=0) ){
            index = vec_puntos
            vec_puntos = vector(length=length(vec_niveles))
            vec_puntos[index] = TRUE
        }

        if(length(vec_niveles)==0){
            index = vec_puntos
            vec_puntos = n[[5]]$splitpoint
        }

        if(index==0){
            if(nextNodeID==n$right$nodeID){
                vec_puntos = !vec_puntos
            }else{
                vec_puntos = !!vec_puntos
            }
            if(i != 1) {
                for(j in 1:(length(Path)-1)){
                    if(length(variablesNombres)>=j){
                        if( variablesNombres[j]==vec_nombre){
                            vec_puntos = vec_puntos*variablesPuntos[[j]]
                        }
                    }
                }
                vec_puntos = vec_puntos==1
            }   
            SB = "="
        }else{
            if(nextNodeID==n$right$nodeID){
                SB = ">"
            }else{
                SB = "<="
            }

        }

        variablesPuntos[[i]] = vec_puntos       
        variablesNombres[i] = vec_nombre

        if(length(vec_niveles)==0){
            descripcion = vec_puntos
        }else{
            descripcion = paste(vec_niveles[vec_puntos],collapse=", ")
        }
        Path2 <- paste(c(Path2, paste(c(variablesNombres[i],SB,"{",descripcion, "}"),collapse=" ")
                        ),
                       collapse = "; ")
    }

    # Output
    ResulTable <- rbind(ResulTable, cbind(Node = Node, Path = Path2))
  }

    we = weights(ct)
    c0 = as.matrix(where(ct))
    c3 = sapply(we, function(w) sum(w))
    c3 = as.matrix(unique(cbind(c0,c3)))
    Counts = as.matrix(c3[,2])
    c2 = drop(Predict(ct))
    Means = as.matrix(unique(c2))

    ResulTable = data.frame(ResulTable,Means,Counts)
    ResulTable  = ResulTable[ order(ResulTable$Means) ,]

    ResulTable$TruePath =  apply(as.data.frame(ResulTable$Path),1, getReglaFinal)

    ResulTable2 = ResulTable

    ResulTable2$SQL <- paste("WHEN ",gsub("\\'([-+]?([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+))\\'", "\\1",gsub("\\, ", "','", gsub(" \\}", "')", gsub("\\{ ", "('", gsub("\\;", " AND ", ResulTable2$TruePath)))))," THEN ")

    cols <- c( 'SQL' , 'Node' )
    ResulTable2$SQL <- apply(  ResulTable2[ , cols ] ,1 , paste , collapse = "'Nodo " )

    ResulTable2$SQL <- gsub("THEN'", "THEN '", gsub(" '", "'",  paste(ResulTable2$SQL,"'")))

    ResultadoFinal = list()

    ResultadoFinal$PreTable = ResulTable
    ResultadoFinal$Table = ResulTable
    ResultadoFinal$Table$Path = ResultadoFinal$Table$TruePath
    ResultadoFinal$Table$TruePath = NULL
    ResultadoFinal$SQL = paste(" CASE ",paste(ResulTable2$SQL,sep="",collapse=" ")," END ",collapse="")

    return(ResultadoFinal)
}#CtreePathFuncAllCat
```

Here is a test:

```
library(party)
#With ordered factors
TreeModel1 = ctree(PB~ME+SYMPT+HIST+BSE+DECT, data = mammoexp)
Result2 <- CtreePathFuncAllCat(TreeModel1)
Result2
##$PreTable
##  Node                                                Path    Means Counts
##3    7    DECT > { Somewhat likely }; SYMPT > { Disagree } 6.526316    114
##2    6   DECT > { Somewhat likely }; SYMPT <= { Disagree } 7.640000    175
##1    4  DECT <= { Somewhat likely }; DECT > { Not likely } 8.161905    105
##4    3 DECT <= { Somewhat likely }; DECT <= { Not likely } 9.833333     18
##                                          TruePath
##3   DECT > { Somewhat likely }; SYMPT > { Disagree }
##2  DECT > { Somewhat likely }; SYMPT <= { Disagree }
##1 DECT <= { Somewhat likely }; DECT > { Not likely }
##4                             DECT <= { Not likely }
##
##$Table
##  Node                                               Path    Means Counts
##3    7   DECT > { Somewhat likely }; SYMPT > { Disagree } 6.526316    114
##2    6  DECT > { Somewhat likely }; SYMPT <= { Disagree } 7.640000    175
##1    4 DECT <= { Somewhat likely }; DECT > { Not likely } 8.161905    105
##4    3                             DECT <= { Not likely } 9.833333     18
##
##$SQL
##[1] " CASE  WHEN  DECT > ('Somewhat likely') AND  SYMPT > ('Disagree')  THEN 'Nodo 7' WHEN  DECT > ('Somewhat likely') AND  SYMPT <= ('Disagree')  THEN 'Nodo 6' WHEN  DECT <= ('Somewhat likely') AND  DECT > ('Not likely')  THEN 'Nodo 4' WHEN  DECT <= ('Not likely')  THEN 'Nodo 3'  END "


#With unordered factors
TreeModel2 = ctree(count~spray, data = InsectSprays)
plot(TreeModel2, type="simple")
Result2 <- CtreePathFuncAllCat(TreeModel2)
Result2
##$PreTable
##Node                                  Path     Means Counts            TruePath
##2    5 spray = { C, D, E }; spray = { C, E }  2.791667     24    spray = { C, E }
##3    4    spray = { C, D, E }; spray = { D }  4.916667     12       spray = { D }
##1    2                   spray = { A, B, F } 15.500000     36 spray = { A, B, F }
##
##$Table
##Node                Path     Means Counts
##2    5    spray = { C, E }  2.791667     24
##3    4       spray = { D }  4.916667     12
##1    2 spray = { A, B, F } 15.500000     36
##
##$SQL
##[1] " CASE  WHEN  spray = ('C','E')  THEN 'Nodo 5' WHEN  spray = ('D')  THEN 'Nodo 4' WHEN  spray = ('A','B','F')  THEN 'Nodo 2'  END "

#With continuous variables
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
TreeModel3 <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq,  controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
Result2 <- CtreePathFuncAllCat(TreeModel3)
Result2
##$PreTable
##  Node                                           Path    Means Counts
##1    5 Temp <= { 82 }; Wind > { 6.9 }; Temp <= { 77 } 18.47917     48
##3    6  Temp <= { 82 }; Wind > { 6.9 }; Temp > { 77 } 31.14286     21
##4    9                 Temp > { 82 }; Wind > { 10.3 } 48.71429      7
##2    3                Temp <= { 82 }; Wind <= { 6.9 } 55.60000     10
##5    8                Temp > { 82 }; Wind <= { 10.3 } 81.63333     30
##                                     TruePath
##1                Temp <= { 77 }; Wind > { 6.9 }
##3 Temp <= { 82 }; Wind > { 6.9 }; Temp > { 77 }
##4                Temp > { 82 }; Wind > { 10.3 }
##2               Temp <= { 82 }; Wind <= { 6.9 }
##5               Temp > { 82 }; Wind <= { 10.3 }
##
##$Table
##  Node                                          Path    Means Counts
##1    5                Temp <= { 77 }; Wind > { 6.9 } 18.47917     48
##3    6 Temp <= { 82 }; Wind > { 6.9 }; Temp > { 77 } 31.14286     21
##4    9                Temp > { 82 }; Wind > { 10.3 } 48.71429      7
##2    3               Temp <= { 82 }; Wind <= { 6.9 } 55.60000     10
##5    8               Temp > { 82 }; Wind <= { 10.3 } 81.63333     30
##
##$SQL
##[1] " CASE  WHEN  Temp <= (77) AND  Wind > (6.9)  THEN 'Nodo 5' WHEN  Temp <= (82) AND  Wind > (6.9) AND  Temp > (77)  THEN 'Nodo 6' WHEN  Temp > (82) AND  Wind > (10.3)  THEN 'Nodo 9' WHEN  Temp <= (82) AND  Wind <= (6.9)  THEN 'Nodo 3' WHEN  Temp > (82) AND  Wind <= (10.3)  THEN 'Nodo 8'  END "
```

Update! Now the function supports mix of categorical and numerical variables!

Comment: Good work with this, however, it only appears to work for categorical variables: When I tried this on the results of the airct tree CtreePathFuncAllCat(ct), it returns the splitting fields, but not the splitting criteria. Any idea how to get the path for categorical and continuous variables?

Comment: @clevelandfrowns I update the function, and now works with continous and categorical data.

Answer (score 2):

The `CtreePathFunc` function rewritten in more of a Hadley-verse (and I think more comprehensible) way. Also handling categorical variables.

```
library(magrittr)
readSplitter <- function(nodeSplit){
  splitPoint <- nodeSplit$splitpoint
  if("levels" %>% is_in(splitPoint %>% attributes %>% names)){
    splitPoint %>% attr("levels") %>% .[splitPoint]
  }else{
    splitPoint %>% as.numeric
  }
}

hasWeigths <- function(ct, path, terminalNode, pathNumber){
  ct %>%
    nodes(pathNumber %>% equals(path %>% length) %>% ifelse(terminalNode, path[pathNumber + 1]) ) %>%
    .[[1]] %>% use_series("weights") %>% as.logical %>% which
}

dataFilter <- function(ct, dts, path, terminalNode, pathNumber){
  whichWeights <- hasWeigths(ct, path, terminalNode, pathNumber)
  nodes(ct, path[pathNumber])[[1]][[5]] %>%
    buildDataFilter(dts, whichWeights)
}

buildDataFilter <- function(nodeSplit, ...) UseMethod("buildDataFilter")

buildDataFilter.nominalSplit <-
  function(nodeSplit, dts, whichWeights){
    varName <- nodeSplit$variableName
    includedLevels <- dts[ whichWeights
                          ,varName] %>% unique
    paste( varName, "=="
          ,includedLevels %>% paste(collapse = ", ") %>% paste0("{", ., "}"))
  }

buildDataFilter.orderedSplit <-
  function(nodeSplit, dts, whichWeights){
    varName <- nodeSplit$variableName
    splitter <- nodeSplit %>% readSplitter

    dts[ whichWeights
        ,varName] %>%
          is_weakly_less_than(splitter) %>%
          all %>%
          ifelse("<=" ,">") %>%
          paste(varName, ., splitter)
}

readTerminalNodePaths <- function (ct, dts) {

  nodeWeights <- function(Node) nodes(ct, Node)[[1]]$weights
  sgmnts <- ct %>% where %>% unique
  nodesFirstTreeWeightIsOne <- function(node) nodes(ct, node)[[1]][2][[1]] == 1

  # Take the inner nodes smaller than the selected terminal node
  innerNodes <-
    function(Node) setdiff( 1:(Node - 1)
                           ,sgmnts[sgmnts < Node])
  pathForTerminalNode <- function(terminalNode){
    innerNodes(terminalNode) %>%
      sapply(function(innerNode){
        if(any(nodeWeights(terminalNode) & nodesFirstTreeWeightIsOne(innerNode))) innerNode
       }) %>%
      unlist
  }

  # Find the splits criteria
  sgmnts %>% sapply(function(terminalNode){ #

    path <- terminalNode %>% pathForTerminalNode

    path %>% length %>% seq %>%
      sapply(function(nodeNumber){
        dataFilter(ct, dts, path, terminalNode, nodeNumber)
       }, simplify = FALSE) %>%
      unlist %>% paste(collapse = " & ") %>%
      data.frame(Node = terminalNode, Path = .)

  }, simplify = FALSE) %>%
    Reduce(f = rbind)
}
```

Testing

```
shiftFirstPart <- function(vctr, divideBy, proportion = .5){
    vctr[vctr %>% length %>% multiply_by(proportion) %>% round %>% seq] %<>% divide_by(divideBy)
  vctr
}
set.seed(11)
n <- 13000
gdt <- 
  data.frame( is_buyer = runif(n) %>% shiftFirstPart(1.5) %>% round %>% factor(labels = c("no", "yes"))
             ,age = runif(n) %>% shiftFirstPart(1.5) %>%
               cut(breaks = c(0, .3, .6, 1), include_lowest = TRUE, ordered_result = TRUE, labels = c("low", "mid", "high"))
             ,city = runif(n) %>% shiftFirstPart(1.5) %>%
               cut(breaks = c(0, .3, .6, 1), include_lowest = TRUE, labels = c("Chigaco", "Boston", "Memphis"))
             ,point = runif(n) %>% shiftFirstPart(1.2)
             )

gct <- ctree( is_buyer ~ ., data = gdt)
readTerminalNodePaths(gct, gdt)
```

Comment: This is a really cool function, not sure I totally understand how it works yet, but is there a simple way to modify it to get the paths for *all* nodes instead of just the terminal ones?

Comment: sorry for the silly question but which library includes the function 'where' ?

Comment: @Manuel Chirouze, `party`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution which is recursive so it runs well on larger trees as well. Here's a demo, followed by the code itself:

```
library(partykit)
# Make a mixture of continuous and categorical vars:
a <- ctree(Sepal.Length ~ Species + Sepal.Width, data = iris)
partykit_res <- partykit:::.list.rules.party(a)
# printing partykit_res you'll see it contains all splits
# on the path, not just the resulting final splits.
suggested_res <- tree_leaves_segments(a)

suggested_res

[1] "Sepal.Width <= 3.2, Species in {setosa}"         
[2] "3.6 >= Sepal.Width > 3.2, Species in {setosa}"   
[3] "Sepal.Width > 3.6, Species in {setosa}"          
[4] "Sepal.Width <= 2.7, Species in {versicolor}"     
[5] "Sepal.Width <= 2.7, Species in {virginica}"      
[6] "Sepal.Width > 2.7, Species in {versicolor}"      
[7] "2.8 >= Sepal.Width > 2.7, Species in {virginica}"
[8] "Sepal.Width > 2.8, Species in {virginica}"
```

And here's the implementation code:

```
tree_leaves_segments <- function(tree) {
  group_df_init <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0)), nm = c("var", "op", "val"))
  parent <- list(tree = tree, group_df = group_df_init)
  leaf_segments <- parent_child_dfs(parent)
  leaf_segments <- leaf_segments[seq(2, length(leaf_segments), 2)]
  if (length(leaf_segments) == 1) { # root
    leaf_segments <- list(group_df = data.frame(var = "root", op = "", val = ""))
  }
  leaf_segments <- sapply(leaf_segments, function(leaf) {
    collapsed_groups <- tapply(1:nrow(leaf), leaf$var, function(idx) {
      g <- leaf[idx, ]
      return(collapse_group_df(g))
    })
    merged_collapsed_groups <- paste0(collapsed_groups, collapse = ", ")
    return(merged_collapsed_groups)
  })
  return(unname(leaf_segments))
}

collapse_group_df <- function(g) {
  if (length(g$var) == 2) {
    upper <- which(substr(g$op, 1, 1) == "<")
    upper_op <- sub(pattern = "<", replacement = ">", x = g$op[upper])
    upper_op <- trimws(upper_op)
    lower <- which(substr(g$op, 1, 1) == ">")
    lower_op <- trimws(g$op[lower])
    return(paste(g$val[upper], upper_op, g$var[1], lower_op, g$val[lower], sep = " "))
  } else {
    if (g$op == "in") {
      prefix <- "{"
      suffix <- "}"
    } else {
      prefix <- ""
      suffix <- ""
      g$op <- trimws(g$op)
    }
    return(trimws(paste0(g$var, " ", g$op, " ", prefix, g$val, suffix)))
  }
}

parent_child_dfs <- function(parent) {
  split <- parent$tree[[1]]$node$split
  if (is.null(split)) {
    return(parent)
  } else {
    slabs <- partykit::character_split(split, data = parent$tree[[1]]$data)
    dir <- substr(slabs$levels, 1, 2)
    if (all(dir %in% c("< ", "> ", "<=", ">="))) {
      val <- sub("^<= |^>= |^< |^> ", "", slabs$levels)
    } else {
      val <- slabs$levels
      dir <- rep("in", length(dir))
    }
    group_dfs <- lapply(1:length(val), function(i) {
      data.frame(var = slabs$name, op = dir[i], val = val[i])
    })
    nodes <- lapply(1:length(group_dfs), function(i) {
      group_df <- merge_group_dfs(group_dfs[[i]], parent$group_df)
      kid_id <- parent$tree$node$kids[[i]]$id
      node <- list(tree = parent$tree[[kid_id]], group_df = group_df)
      return(node)
    })
    nodes <- unlist(lapply(nodes, parent_child_dfs), recursive = F)
    return(nodes)
  }
}

merge_group_dfs <- function(group_df, parent_group_df) {
  match_idx <- which(group_df$var == parent_group_df$var)
  if (length(match_idx) == 0) {
    ans <- rbind(parent_group_df, group_df)
  } else {
    if (group_df$op == "in") {
      parent_group_df$val[match_idx] <- group_df$val
    } else {
      for (idx in match_idx) {
        if (group_df$op == parent_group_df$op[[idx]]) {
          parent_group_df$val[[idx]] <- group_df$val
        } else if (length(match_idx) == 1) {
          parent_group_df <- rbind(parent_group_df, group_df)
        }
      }
    }
    ans <- parent_group_df
  }
  return(ans)
}
```