# How to extract the splitting rules for the terminal nodes of ctree()

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I have a data set with 6 categorical variables with levels ranging from 5 to 28. I have obtained an output from *ctree()* (party package) with 17 terminal nodes. I have followed the inputs by @Galled from [ctree() - How to get the list of splitting conditions for each terminal node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443203/ctree-how-to-get-the-list-of-splitting-conditions-for-each-terminal-node?rq=1) to arrive at my desired output.

But, I'm getting the following error post running the code:

```
Error in data.frame(ResulTable, Means, Counts) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 17, 2
```

I have tried adding this extra lines:

```
ResulTable <- rbind(ResulTable, cbind(Node = Node, Path = Path2))

ResulTable$Node <- rownames(ResulTable)

melt(ResulTable)
```

but no success so far. Any pointers on where it is going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend to use the new `partykit` implementation of `ctree()` rather than the old `party` package, then you can use the function `.list.rules.party()`. This is not officially exported, yet, but can be leveraged to extract the desired information.

```
library("partykit")
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
ct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq)
partykit:::.list.rules.party(ct)
##                                      3                                      5 
##             "Temp <= 82 & Wind <= 6.9" "Temp <= 82 & Wind > 6.9 & Temp <= 77" 
##                                      6                                      8 
##  "Temp <= 82 & Wind > 6.9 & Temp > 77"             "Temp > 82 & Wind <= 10.3" 
##                                      9 
##              "Temp > 82 & Wind > 10.3"
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. With the above code, I'm getting this error: Error in UseMethod("nodeids") : 
  no applicable method for 'nodeids' applied to an object of class "c('BinaryTree', 'BinaryTreePartition')"

Comment: Then you have fitted your tree with `party::ctree` not with `partykit::ctree`. Make sure that you do not load both packages simultaneously. This wis bound to lead to confusion...

Comment: Running ctree with partykit package (with the default control parameters) is taking an indefinite time as compared to running ctree with party package which was much faster. I have a dataset with 100K rows and 6 columns. I'm running R version 3.1.3 on a 32-bit 64 GB machine. Any inputs on this?

Comment: The old `party` implementation could run into numerical problems when comparing p-values from datasets with hundreds of thousands of observations. The new `partykit` implementation uses log-p-values instead which is numerically more stable. For your data this appears to lead to differences in the splitting with `partykit` continuing longer. I would recommend to not use the default values only but restrict `mincriterion`, `minbucket`, or `maxdepth` to values that are better suited for your data.