# Extracting list of the split of a lmtree object

Tags: r, partitioning, party

I am using the lmtree function from the partykit package
and I am looking for a function similar to the path.rpart function, ie,
a function which gives in a list the splits on the path from the root to the selected node.

It would like something similar to this  :

```
 set.seed(1)
 library(rpart)
 x=runif(100);z=runif(100);y=jitter(ifelse(z>.5,2*x,3*x+2),amount=.1);
 rp=rpart(x~y)
 path.rpart(rp,5)

 #node number: 5 
 #root
 #y< 0.8785
 #y>=0.4081
```

with lmtree :

```
 library(partykit)
 tr=lmtree(x~y|z)
 #and here I need a function similar to path.rpart
```

I checked the node_party and get_paths functions but it is not what I need.
Does any one have suggestions for extracting this info from the lmtree object ?
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Its easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the code you used to build your model. Describe what the expected result is for that input so possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Comment: Too vague to be answered because you haven't explained clearly what you want.

Comment: @MrFlick and InfiniteFlashChess You right I edited my question

Comment: use `set.seed()` with your example so we can get the same sample data values. Right now when I run your code there is no node 10 so I get an error.

Comment: Done, thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Models of class `lmtree` inherit from `party` just like the output from `ctree()`. Hence, the same approaches that are discussed here on SO for `ctree()` output can also be applied to `lmtree()` output. Namely, you can use the (still unexported) `.list.rules.party()` function:

```
partykit:::.list.rules.party(tr)
##                        2                        3 
## "z <= 0.495593577856198"  "z > 0.495593577856198"
```

For further adaptations see: also:

- [ctree() - How to get the list of splitting conditions for each terminal node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443203/ctree-how-to-get-the-list-of-splitting-conditions-for-each-terminal-node/29999993#29999993)
- [Get decision tree rule/path pattern for every row of predicted dataset for rpart/ctree package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618490/get-decision-tree-rule-path-pattern-for-every-row-of-predicted-dataset-for-rpart/29638602#29638602)

Comment: Exactly what I need ! Thx