# A chaotic decision tree with the "party" package

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I'm trying to get a decision tree from the code:

```
library(party)
tree <- data.frame(mi[,-2])
levels(tree$OS_Gatunek) <- c("ta", "th", "tl", "to", "tp") # shortening species names
model <- ctree(OS_Gatunek~., data=tree)
plot(model)
```

My data look like this:

```
> str(mi)
'data.frame':   4393 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ OS_Gatunek       : Factor w/ 5 levels "Taraxacum ancistrolobum",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ PH_CreateDate    : Factor w/ 15 levels "2016-04-06","2016-04-19",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ L_Dl             : num  7.91 8.96 10.18 10.09 9.4 ...
 $ L_SzerMaksOs     : num  1.93 3.98 3.12 4.04 2.75 2.69 3.69 3.23 2.3 2.49 ...
 $ L_DlMax          : num  3.51 4.08 5.58 5.04 3.99 3.6 5.65 4.62 3.33 4.18 ...
 $ KS_DlSk_Sr       : num  1.78 3.28 2.88 4.19 1.88 2.47 3.11 4.04 1.61 2.09 ...
 $ KS_Dl_Sr         : num  1.68 2.83 2.62 3.84 1.68 2.12 2.87 3.8 1.44 1.86 ...
 $ KS_Sz            : num  1.35 3.41 2.38 3.31 1.66 2.35 2.45 2.96 1.57 1.9 ...
 $ KB_DlSkos_Sr     : num  1.07 1.94 1.84 1.69 1.25 1.49 1.96 1.77 1.43 1.55 ...
 $ KB_Dl_Sr         : num  0.62 1.49 1.12 1.34 0.86 0.77 1.22 1.07 0.82 1.05 ...
 $ KB_Szer_Sr       : num  0.85 1.23 1.46 0.94 0.89 1.32 1.53 1.41 1.17 1.14 ...
 $ KB_SzerPierwKlapy: num  1.75 3.99 2.9 4.1 2.34 2.75 3.11 3.39 1.96 2.46 ...
 $ I_Dl_Sr          : num  0.25 0.86 0.48 0.61 0.44 0.41 0.7 0.86 0.14 0.59 ...
 $ I_SzOs           : num  0.37 0.83 0.47 0.87 0.39 0.73 0.53 0.96 0.4 0.33 ...
 $ I_DlSz_Sr        : num  2.3 4.08 3.35 5.23 2.34 3.39 3.22 4.43 1.96 2.55 ...
 $ O_Dl_Sr          : num  0.67 0.75 2.02 0.85 0.74 1.4 1.07 0.26 0.6 0.96 ...
 $ O_SzerOs         : num  1.35 1.59 1.31 0.91 1.08 0.94 1.18 0.84 1.71 0.93 ...
 $ O_SzerOskrz_Sr   : num  0.55 0.65 0.48 0.34 0.39 0.31 0.49 0.29 0.74 0.27 ...
```

But the tree looks like this:

[image: My tree]

And I would really like it to look like this (taken from: https://ademos.people.uic.edu/Chapter24.html):

[image: The correct tree]

What should my code look like? I'll be grateful for all suggestions.

Comment: Yes.  Thank you for fixing.

Comment: The code looks ok but for some reason the tree becomes very large (more than 200 nodes). I'm not sure why exactly this happens. Can you share the data so that this is fully reproducible?

Comment: Unfortunately, the boss did not let me share the data :-(. But I changed the code a bit: `model <- ctree (OS_Gatunek ~., Data = tree, controls = ctree_control (mincriterion = 0.95))` (from: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399510/how-to-implement-the-output-of-decision-tree-built-using-the-ctree-party-packag]) and already there are "only" 19 nodes. I will try to combine something in this direction

Comment: Eventually it succeeded with the parameter `controls = ctree_control(maxdepth=3)`. I saved the plot as `pdf(file="C:/Users/moje/Desktop/mi.pdf", width=15, height=5)` and I succeeded :-). It looks decent. Nevertheless, thank you very much for the comments :-).